# ControlledAccessException on using Display.screenshot()

Tags: blackberry

I am using `Display.screenshot()` to get a screen shot for the current displayed screen.
My application has all available persmissions set to allow,
it works well in all device application, but it doesn't work on Facebook and Twitter app -
on those apps i got an exception:

> Error: net.rim.device.api.system.ControlledAccessException: Unauthorized attempt to attach to this application

what should I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be calling `Application.getApplication()` somewhere in the code.

Your `ApplicationMenuItem` code generally runs within the UI application whose menu it is launched from. So when you click your ApplicationMenuItem within facebook app, it executes within the event dispatcher thread of facebook app.

However, since your code is not a part of the facebook app, it can't access its Application Object using the `Application.getApplication()` method.

If you are not calling this method yourself, maybe `Display.screenshot()` calls it internally. To solve this, you need to run the code in your app's event dispatcher thread. This can be done by using the special method `addMenuItem(long, ApplicationMenuItem, ApplicationDescriptor)` while registering the menu item and passing it your app descriptor.